# `build': undefined method `new' for ExceptionNotifier:Module (NoMethodError) when executing rails s

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I just upgraded to Mac OSX Mavericks and to Ruby 1.9.3-p392 and now when I try to run `rails s` in one of my app I get the following error:

```
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.2.13 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
/Users/titouanvanbelle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:43:in `build': undefined method `new' for ExceptionNotifier:Module (NoMethodError)
    from /Users/titouanvanbelle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:113:in `block in build'
    from /Users/titouanvanbelle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:113:in `each'
    from /Users/titouanvanbelle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:113:in `inject'
    from /Users/titouanvanbelle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:113:in `build'
    from /Users/titouanvanbelle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/engine.rb:470:in `app'
    from /Users/titouanvanbelle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:31:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
    from /Users/titouanvanbelle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from /Users/titouanvanbelle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from /Users/titouanvanbelle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
    from /Users/titouanvanbelle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
    from /Users/titouanvanbelle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    from /Users/titouanvanbelle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
    from /Users/titouanvanbelle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
    from /Users/titouanvanbelle/Documents/workspace/paymy/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/titouanvanbelle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /Users/titouanvanbelle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
    from /Users/titouanvanbelle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/titouanvanbelle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /Users/titouanvanbelle/Documents/workspace/paymy/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
    from /Users/titouanvanbelle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
    from /Users/titouanvanbelle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
    from /Users/titouanvanbelle/Documents/workspace/paymy/config.ru:in `new'
    from /Users/titouanvanbelle/Documents/workspace/paymy/config.ru:in `<main>'
    from /Users/titouanvanbelle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `eval'
    from /Users/titouanvanbelle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
    from /Users/titouanvanbelle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:200:in `app'
    from /Users/titouanvanbelle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:46:in `app'
    from /Users/titouanvanbelle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:304:in `wrapped_app'
    from /Users/titouanvanbelle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:254:in `start'
    from /Users/titouanvanbelle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
    from /Users/titouanvanbelle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /Users/titouanvanbelle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
    from /Users/titouanvanbelle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

This is my Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.13'
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', "3.0.1"

# Database support:
gem 'pg'

# Use native JSON extension:
gem 'json'

# Use RABL to build API responses:
gem 'rabl'

# HTML parsing for press page
gem 'nokogiri'

# Authentication & authorization:
gem 'omniauth-facebook'
gem 'consul'
gem 'omniauth-identity'

# Pagination
gem 'will_paginate'
gem 'will_paginate-bootstrap'
gem 'foundation-will_paginate'

# Facebook
gem 'koala'

# Utility
gem 'modularity'
gem 'has_defaults'
gem 'andand'
gem 'gibberish'
gem 'state_machine'
gem 'exception_notification'
gem 'edge_rider'
gem 'rest-client'

gem 'haml-rails'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 2.1.1.0'
gem 'zurb-foundation', '~> 4.1.6'
gem 'compass-rails'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'inherited_resources'

# GUI
gem 'simple_form'

# background processing
gem 'delayed_job_active_record'

# Payment
gem 'king_dtaus'

group :deploy do
  # cron
  gem 'whenever', require: false
end


# Gems used for development and testing
# and not required in production.
group :development, :test do
  gem 'machinist', '<2'
  gem 'machinist_callbacks'
  gem 'faker'
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'cucumber-rails', require: false
  gem 'cucumber_factory'
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem 'timecop'
  gem 'capybara', '<2'
  gem 'spreewald'
  gem 'cucumber_spinner'
  gem 'launchy'
  gem 'rspec_candy'
  gem 'pry'
  gem 'debugger'
  gem 'quiet_assets'
  gem 'letter_opener'
  gem 'poltergeist'
  gem 'guard-rspec'
  gem 'guard-cucumber'
  gem 'parallel_tests'
end

group :test do
  gem 'shoulda-matchers'
end

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
# group :assets do
#   gem 'sass-rails'
#   gem 'coffee-rails'
#   gem 'uglifier'
# end
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails', '~> 3.1'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
  gem 'execjs'
  gem 'therubyracer'
end

group :development do
  gem 'better_errors'
  gem 'meta_request'
  gem 'binding_of_caller'
  gem 'ruby-graphviz', '<= 1.0.8'
end

# Sencha theming with compass:
gem 'compass', group: :development


group :deployment do
  gem 'capistrano'
  gem 'capistrano_colors'
  gem 'rvm-capistrano'
end

group :server do
  gem 'god'
  gem 'daemons'
end
```

Versions I am using are:

Ruby: ruby-1.9.3-p392
Rails: Rails 3.2.13

Not sure what else to tell you, but just ask. I'll add as much information as I can.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue is with "exception_notification" gem, you have had updated to version 4.x.

You must change:

```
YOUR_APP::Application.config.middleware.use ExceptionNotifier
```

to

```
YOUR_APP::Application.config.middleware.use ExceptionNotification::Rack
```

More info: https://github.com/smartinez87/exception_notification#upgrading-to-4x-version

Comment: I had this issue, but I had a correct configuration in my staging.rb file.  The issue was that the other environments had the incorrect configuration settings.  So, it was a configuration issue, just not where I was expecting it to be.